# As a US citizen, can I continue to receive my social security benefits while visiting Sweden for an extended period?

Tags: united-states, social-security, travel, sweden

I'm planning to visit Sweden for around 80 days as a tourist (I'm a US citizen), and I would like to know what the rules regarding receiving social security benefits are when you are away from the US for so long. I found this PDF: https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10137.pdf

However, while the PDF does say that I can continue to receive benefits even when outside the United States provided I'm still eligible and in a country where the US can send payments (which Sweden is), what's not clear to me is whether staying outside of the US for an extended period such as 80 days would affect my eligibility. I would assume that it does not affect it given that the PDF doesn't say any such thing, but it's hard to be certain based on that something is not written.

To summarise, would visiting Sweden as a tourist for 80 days affect my eligibility to receive social security benefits as a citizen of the USA?

Comment: This is mostly towards those who are not US citizens (foreign workers etc) who accumulated US SSA benefits. US citizens are considered US residents for tax/SSA purposes no matter where they physically reside.

Comment: The question confuses me.  You’re a US citizen with a US bank account where the money goes.  **You’ll be coming back**, and the SSA won’t know you’re gone

Comment: A better question to Google is whether or not expats still get Ss.  Id they do, you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF you linked says

> If you are not a U.S. citizen or you
> do not meet one of the conditions for
> continued payments, we will stop your
> payments after you have been outside
> the United States for six full calendar
> months.

So they won't stop them if you are just away for 80 days. While it technically doesn't positively affirm that, it is pretty clear from the way the document is written that they are only interested in long-term residence overseas, not short-term tourist trips.